# Multiple Container Views with Delegates

Tags: ios, delegates, segue, uicontainerview

I have a View controller that contains 2 Container Views. One of them has a scroll-view one of them is just a small view.

Now, I want to communicate between all 3, the way I'm doing it is by using the main ViewController as a delegate for the other 2. I originally didnt know how to set them as delegates, as there is no transition or presentation of the other ones (they're just there)

After asking here a few months back I got the following answer:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "embedSegue") {
        resultsVC = (segue.destination as! GoalsVC)
        resultsVC.calcDelegate = self
    }
}
```

However, I dont know how to do this for BOTH contained views. they are both using the same segue so I cant have them both have the same ViewController.

I was thinking using storyboard IDs but how do I reference them in the prepareforsegue?
would it be something like

```
if (segue.identifier == "embedSegue" && storyboardidentifier = "myVC1") {
    resultsVC = (segue.destination as! GoalsVC)
    resultsVC.calcDelegate = self
} else if (segue.identifier == "embedSegue" && storyboardidentifier = "myVC2") {
    otherVC = (segue.destination as! NewVC)
    resultsVC.calcDelegate = self
}
```

Except I dont know the exact code to reference the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you use ? instead of ! you can use the success of the conversion to indicate whether you have the correct viewcontroller. The code would be as follows

```
if segue.identifier == "embedSegue" {
    if let resultsVC = segue.destination as? GoalsVC {
        resultsVC.calcDelegate = self
    }
    if let otherVC = segue.destination as? NewVC {
        resultsVC.calcDelegate = self
    }
}
```

You could simplify this code even further by delegating the setting of the delegate. Setup a new delegate, ensure your two embedded viewcontrollers conform to it. In the code below I have assumed the delegate you have already written is called CalcDelegate.

```
protocol CalcDelegateDelegate {
    var calcDelegate : CalcDelegate? {get set}
}

class GoalsVC : UIViewController, CalcDelegateDelegate {
    var calcDelegate: CalcDelegate? = nil
}

class NewVC : UIViewController, CalcDelegateDelegate {
    var calcDelegate: CalcDelegate? = nil
}
```

Then your prepare code is simplified to

```
if segue.identifier == "embedSegue" {
    if var delegate = segue.destination as? CalcDelegateDelegate {
        delegate.calcDelegate = self
    }
}
```

Any new view controller that is embedded in your main controller just needs to conform to the delegate and it automatically gets the calcDelegate and can communicate with your other view controllers.